# Getting Server Error while creating Google Ads's VideoRedirectCreative using python

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm trying to create Creative [VideoRedirectCreative](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202305/CreativeService.VideoRedirectCreative) using Python. I have uploaded the in Cloudflare Stream and I'm trying to upload hsl playback url. Here my code

```py
def create_vast_creative(client, advertiser_id):
    # Get the CreativeService.
    creative_service = client.GetService("CreativeService", version="v202311")

    # Create a VAST redirect creative.
    vast_creative = {
        "xsi_type": "VideoRedirectCreative",
        "name": f"Video creative - {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")}",
        "advertiserId": advertiser_id,
        "size": {"width": "640", "height": "480"},
        "duration": 10000,
        "skippableAdType": "DISABLED",
        "destinationUrlType": "CLICK_TO_WEB",
        "destinationUrl": "https://www.google.com/",
        "videoAssets": {
            "redirectUrl": video_url,
            "metadata": {
                "mimeType":"VIDEO_MP4",
                "deliveryType": "UNKNOWN",
                "scalableType": "NOT_SCALABLE",
                "duration": 75990,
                "size":  {
                    "width": 1920,
                    "height": 1080
                },
                "bitRate": 4000,
            }
        },
    }

    result = creative_service.createCreatives([vast_creative])

    # Print out some information for each created creative.
    for creative in result:
        print(creative)
```

but I'm getting this error

```
Error summary: {'faultMessage': '[ServerError.SERVER_ERROR @ ]', 'requestId': 'e11e5ac856990f32992ba6ef7cb269ed', 'responseTime': '422', 'serviceName': 'CreativeService', 'methodName': 'createCreatives'}
```

and when I'm trying to use [VideoCreative](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202305/CreativeService.VideoCreative) method like,

```py
    vast_creative = {
        "xsi_type": "VideoCreative",
        "name": f"Video creative - {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")}",
        "advertiserId": advertiser_id,
        "size": {"width": "640", "height": "480"},
        "duration": 10000,
        "skippableAdType": "DISABLED",
        "destinationUrlType": "CLICK_TO_WEB",
        "destinationUrl": "https://www.google.com/",
        "videoSourceUrl": video_url,
    }
```

then I'm getting

```
googleads.errors.GoogleAdsServerFault: [FeatureError.MISSING_FEATURE @ [0].videoSourceUrl; trigger:'VIDEO_CREATIVES_VIDEO_SOURCE_URL']
```

but it clearly mentioned in their [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202305/CreativeService.VideoCreative#videosourceurl)

and now I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

My main objective is to include creating Google ads and all using my own in-house CMS with minimum clicks and getting the XML file URL for frontend websites to serve video ads.

I'm open to any suggestion to perform this task, which is to upload the video ad using our CMS which is built using ReactJS, and backend using Django Rest Framework